# Is there a way to speed up this for in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

Is there a way to speed up this code in python? I need to run it with over 500k strings and it takes too long.

Each word need to be put inside the matching dictionary.

- example_sent_words = list of 500k strings
- EmojiPos = list of emoji
- EmojiNeg = list of emoji
- OthersEmoji = list of emoji

```
emoji_pos=dict()
emoji_neg=dict()
emoji_others=dict()

for w in example_sent_words:
            if w in s_EmojiPos:
                remove_username_url.remove(w)
                if w in emoji_pos:
                    emoji_pos[w] += 1
                else:
                    emoji_pos[w] = 1
            elif w in s_EmojiNeg:
                remove_username_url.remove(w)
                if w in emoji_neg:
                    emoji_neg[w] += 1
                else:
                    emoji_neg[w] = 1
            elif w in s_OthersEmoji:
                remove_username_url.remove(w)
                if w in emoji_others:
                    emoji_others[w] += 1
                else:
                    emoji_others[w] = 1
```

edit: I wrote this as suggested:

```
s_AdditionalEmoji = set(AdditionalEmoji)
s_EmojiNeg = set(EmojiNeg)
s_EmojiPos = set(EmojiPos)
```

Comment: Make EmojiPos, EmojNeg, and OthersEmoji into sets, not lists.  It's much faster to test if an item is present in a set instead of a list.

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 5.4. Sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately the time of process is still the same

Answer (score 1):

To cut down on memory usage and speed up checks as well as make sure to check every word, I would suggest:

```
    word_count = len(example_sent_words)
    for i in range(word_count) :
        w = example_sent_words[0]
        if w in EmojiPos:
            example_sent_words.pop(0)
            try:
                emoji_pos[w] += 1
            except:
                emoji_pos[w] = 1
        elif w in EmojiNeg:
            example_sent_words.pop(0)
            try:
                emoji_neg[w] += 1
            except:
                emoji_neg[w] = 1
        elif w in OthersEmoji:
            example_sent_words.pop(0)
            try:
                emoji_others[w] += 1
            except:
                emoji_others[w] = 1
```